# Video card problems after updating BIOS

Tags: laptop, drivers, bios, amd-radeon

**System specs:**

HP ProBook 6540b

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (original)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40 GHz
ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4550
BIOS updated from F.07 to F.21 (can't be rolled back)

**What happened:**
I updated the BIOS drivers from F.07 to F.21. The update was successful without any errors. Upon reboot, the problems started.

**Problem:**

- Driver installation fails or in case it's successful then Catalyst keeps crashing

  [image]
- After installing drivers this starts to happen:

  [image]

  [image]

**Things I've tried:**
- Removing drivers from device manager (the artifacts from programs disappear but I can't play games)
- Installing the latest drivers from ATI's website
- Installing the beta drivers
- Installing the drivers from the CD that came with the laptop
- Fresh install of windows and all of the above

---

Is it possible that the drivers are somehow incompatible with the BIOS? Is the card failing?

Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to install Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you show in the screen shot and example details corrupt video Ram.  That model HP comes with discrete video Ram (512mb) so it's not like your system Ram is bad.  It does point to the issue being specifically with something you can't replace... meaning just the video ram.

It could be a coincidence that this popped up when you updated the BIOS, nothing specifically listed in the revision notes at the HP download page detailing that update state it deals with the video chipset at all... but that doesn't mean much.  It *is* unusual that the problem occurred at the same time.

Everything you did surrounding the drivers is right up there in the HP tech support playbook.  If it was a video driver issue, you would have fixed it within those steps.  Is it possible that the Bios Update was incompatible?  I did see one other BIOS update (F.0c) but if you were using F.07, I don't think you were supposed to replace it with F.0c.

If the system was on warranty, this would be worth a call to HP.  Actually, it's still worth a call to HP.